# Assigning proper variable types when read from a config file [PowerShell]

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to read values from a text file and keep them as variables to use in my script.

This config file contains strings, ints, booleans and an array that can contain strings, ints and booleans.

When I declare the variables outright, I have no problems.  My script functions as expected.  However when I am reading in the config file and trying to create variables based on that, I only get the variables declared as strings.

This creates my config file in the format I would like.

```
Function Create-Config() {
    If (!(Test-Path config.txt)) {
        $currentlocation=Get-Location
        $parentfolder=(get-item $currentlocation).parent.FullName
        New-Item config.txt -ItemType "file"
        Add-Content config.txt "SERVER_NAME=MyServer"
        Add-Content config.txt "SERVER_LOCATION=$currentlocation"
        Add-Content config.txt "BACKUP_LOCATION=$parentfolder\backup"
        Add-Content config.txt "CRAFTBUKKIT=craftbukkit.jar"
        Add-Content config.txt "JAVA_FLAGS=-Xmx1G"
        Add-Content config.txt "CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTIONS=-o True -p 1337"
        Add-Content config.txt "TEST_DEPENDENCIES=True"
        Add-Content config.txt "DELETE_LOG=True"
        Add-Content config.txt "TAKE_BACKUP=True"
        Add-Content config.txt "RESTART_PAUSE=5"
   }
```

}

However, either I need to change how I create my config file, or change how I import those variables.  I want the config file to be as simple as possible.  I am using this code to import the values:

```
Function Load-Variables() {
    Get-Content config.txt | Foreach-Object {
        $var = $_.Split('=')
        New-Variable -Name $var[0] -Scope Script -Value $var[1]
    }
}
```

As you can see, I don't explicitly set the variable, since the variables from the config are different types (booleans, int, array, strings).  However, PowerShell imports these all as strings.  I can import all variables individually (which I may have to do) but I'm still feeling like I will be stuck on the array.

If I declare the array using this command:

```
New-Variable -Name CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTIONS -Option Constant -Value ([array]@('-o',$true,'-p',25565))
```

I get exactly what I want, but I need to import it from the config file instead of declaring the variable in my script.  The java program is a bit finicky, so I cannot just import that value as a string, or it will not get passed properly and those options get ignored.  I've found the only way it works is to have it as an array (as defined above).  I also want to note that there could be many more config file options presented than in my example.

I am not sure what is the better approach - importing the variables to be declared correctly (what I would like to do), or assuming they cannot be imported as anything other than a string and then parsing that string into the proper variable types after.

I have tried declaring the variables before hand and using the Set-Variable command to set the values, but that doesn't work. It very much seems like my variables are being imported with Get-Content as strings from the start instead of the correct types.

Full script is here:
https://gist.github.com/TnTBass/4692f2a00fade7887ce4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any help?

```
$types = @{
SERVER_NAME         = {$args[0]}
SERVER_LOCATION     = {$args[0]}
BACKUP_LOCATION     = {$args[0]}
CRAFTBUKKIT         = {$args[0]}
JAVA_FLAGS          = {$args[0]}
CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTIONS = { ($args[0].split(' ')[0] -as [string]),
                        ([bool]::Parse($args[0].split(' ')[1])),
                        ($args[0].split(' ')[2] -as [string]),
                        ($args[0].split(' ')[3] -as [int]) }
TEST_DEPENDENCIES   = {[bool]::Parse($args[0])}
DELETE_LOG          = {[bool]::Parse($args[0])}
TAKE_BACKUP         = {[bool]::Parse($args[0])}
RESTART_PAUSE       = {$args[0] -as [int]}
}

$ht = [ordered]@{}
gc config.txt |
  foreach {
           $parts = $_.split('=').trim()
           $ht[$parts[0]] = &$types[$parts[0]] $parts[1]
           }

New-object PSObject -Property $ht


SERVER_NAME         : MyServer
SERVER_LOCATION     : C:\testfiles
BACKUP_LOCATION     : C:\\backup
CRAFTBUKKIT         : craftbukkit.jar
JAVA_FLAGS          : -Xmx1G
CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTIONS : {-o, True, -p, 1337}
TEST_DEPENDENCIES   : True
DELETE_LOG          : True
TAKE_BACKUP         : True
RESTART_PAUSE       : 5
```

The $types hash table uses parameter names from your configuration file for the keys, and script blocks that define the typing and data transformation that needs to be done on the string value for that parameter you're reading from the file. As each line is read in from the file, this part of the script:

```
   $parts = $_.split('=').trim()
   $ht[$parts[0]] = &$types[$parts[0]] $parts[1]
```

Splits it at the '=', then looks up the script block for that parameter and invokes it using the value as it's argument.  The results are stored in a hash table ($ht), and then that's used to create an object. You can omit the object creation and just use the hash table to pass your config values if that's more appropriate for your application.

You might need to add some error trapping to test the input data and/or resulting values for production work. but I think the hash table of script blocks is a pretty clean way doing to present the typing and transformation, and should be fairly intuitive to read and easy to maintain in the script if you need to make changes.  The first 5 parameters are string parameters, and are just returned as-is, but you can explicit cast them as [string] in the script block just for clarity.

Comment: That's clever, but it would be nice if you added an explanation.

Comment: You appear to be missing a couple of square brackets.  This:$types$parts[1] should be $types[$parts[1]]

Comment: I can't explain that error. The results I posted were from test data create using your function. What PS version are you using?

Comment: It was entirely my fault, I had attempted to make some changes in your $types declaration.  I reverted back to your exact code and it works.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem.  What was it you wanted to change?

Comment: Entirely unnecessary, but I wanted to declare $types the same way I declare my other variables (Explicitly, using New-Variable).  
I am now attempting to access the hashtable outside of my function, I used to do that with declaring a scope, but I don't see that option.
What you have here seems to do exactly what I want, but I am just trying to make it work with my script.
I also have concerns that the CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTIONS isn't going to be "string, bool, string, int".

Comment: I just noticed your requirement that the array memebers of the "CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTIONS" parameter also required explicit typing.  I updated the script for that.

Comment: If you put that inside a function, you'll need to return the result (either hash table or object) at the end of the function.

Comment: Explicitly setting the CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTIONS is fantastic, thank you.  I don't suppose there is anyway to make that more flexible if the user would add in more options.  (-o false -p 1337 -s 5 --log-pattern %d)
Seems doing that would be fairly difficult.

Also, oddly, I noted if my CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTIONS in my config file is -o false, I always see the array contains -o true.  http://pastebin.com/3UsSEFnx

You have been an enormous help so far, but I don't want to waste your time if this is outside of the scope of the original question.

Comment: Doh! 'False' -as [bool] is $true, because it's a non-null string.  Fortunately [bool] has a Parse static method that recognizes 'True' and 'False'.  Changed to using that. Adding additional arbitrary elements might be possible, but I'd get this much working first and re-vist that later.

Comment: That works like a charm.  I can now import the variables exactly as I want them to be, using the same config file format I had.  You are a wonderful person for helping me out.  I have marked your answer as the accepted answer. :D

If you have any tips for those arbitrary values, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: It's a script block, so you can add whatever if/then logic you want in there to test for the number of elements that the split produces, and add more elements to that array if they exist. That's a fairly straigt-forward exercise you can deveolop outside of the script, and then just move the script block over when you have it working right.

Answer (score 0):

Of course Powershell handles the variable values as strings. That's because it cannot tell string "1337" apart from integer 1337 without some extra help. In order to specify the data type, you need some metadata. There is an format just for that - XML. Now, you don't need to create an XML file by yourself. There are cmdlets `Import-CliXML` and `Export-CliXML` that manage Powershell object serialization.

One could for example save the configuration settings in a hash table and serialize it like so,

```
$cfgSettings = @{ 
"currentlocation" = "my current location";
"parentfolder" = "my backup location";
"SERVER_NAME" = "MyServer";
"SERVER_LOCATION" = $currentlocation;
"BACKUP_LOCATION" = "$parentfolder\backup";
"CRAFTBUKKIT" = "craftbukkit.jar";
"JAVA_FLAGS" = "-Xmx1G";
"CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTIONS" = "-o True -p 1337";
"TEST_DEPENDENCIES" = $true;
"DELETE_LOG" = $true;
"TAKE_BACKUP" = $true;
"RESTART_PAUSE" = 5
}

Export-Clixml -Path myConf.xml -InputObject $cfgSettings
```

The file contains serialized hashtable with data types. For example, DELETE_LOG is a boolean, RESTART_PAUSE an int and so on:

```
  <En>
    <S N="Key">DELETE_LOG</S>
    <B N="Value">true</B>
  </En>
  <En>
    <S N="Key">RESTART_PAUSE</S>
    <I32 N="Value">5</I32>
  </En>
  <En>
    <S N="Key">JAVA_FLAGS</S>
    <S N="Value">-Xmx1G</S>
  </En>
```

Repopulating and accessing the settings hashtable is not hard either:

```
$config = Import-CliXML myConf.xml
$config["DELETE_LOG"] # NB! Case sensitive, "delete_log" is different a key!
True
```

**Edit**

As per how to create the array, here is a sample that uses deserialized data.

Split the options and serialize the values:

```
$config = @{
"CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTION1" = "-o" ;
"CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTION2" = $true ;
"CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTION3" = "-p" ;
"CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTION4" = 1337 }
Export-Clixml -InputObject $config -Path .\temp\conf.xml
```

Deserialize the values and create an array out of them:

```
$config2 = Import-Clixml C:\temp\conf.xml
$array = @( 
$config2["CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTION1"], 
$config2["CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTION2"], 
$config2["CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTION3"], 
$config2["CRAFTBUKKIT_OPTION4"])
```

Print the array contents with type info:

```
$array | % { $("{0} {1}" -f $_, ($_.gettype().name)) }
# Output
-o String
True Boolean
-p String
1337 Int32
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid XML files as they aren't very user friendly.

Lets explore this option more though.  How would I ensure my Array is populated correctly?  I need the -o to be a string, and the True to be a boolean.  There may also be more options added later.  They will always start with a string (-o or -p) but the value may be different everytime (boolean, string, int).

Comment: I appreciate the help, however, XML files are a bit too difficult to modify for the average user.  I have went with @mjolinor's answer.